# How are people handling report email with Fast Reports + Delphi

Tags: delphi, fastreport

As far as I can tell Fast Reports has trouble sending mail through certain providers, including Gmail, freely admit this issue and claim it will be fixed 'in the future'.  It's going on 12 months since I've heard that from their support team with no change.

Anybody out there able to modify their code and/or override their preview form to get an email that works with every server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not heard about those problems - but what we do is when the user presses a 'send via email' button in the previewer we generate a PDF of the report using the FR PDF export component than use the [Jedi JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) to send an email with attachment using the default MAPI client software.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876873/easiest-way-to-compose-outlook-2010-mail-from-delphi/4877682#4877682) has more info.

FastReport, therefore, has no influence over the email sending part and it has been working fine for quite some time.

Comment: How do you change the behavior of the send email button in the previewer? I just re-opened a ticket with FR on this and they re-iterated that they only support basic auth (no ssl for gmail) and that will likely not change.

Comment: We've written our own previewer. It's basically a copy of the standard one but using buttons and styles that match the rest of the app (using DevExpress controls) and using our own code, where appropriate, for the button actions. Didn't actually take that long.

Answer (score 0):

i had problems in the past with sending email thanks to the configuration of the server from my company, using the sender for fast reports of course, 
what i did was use the SendMail event from the frxMailExport component, grabed the params passed and managed to send via indy